# Load google ads dynamically?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I always thought loading google ads dynamically wasn't allowed and then I saw `freerice.com` which seem to do just that.

Is it against TOS to load google ads as a user scrolls down the page. I have a site that loads content dynamically and is basically endless scrolling

Comment: Check if your issue is answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411533/adsense-in-a-ajax-based-application

Comment: To add to my above comment, another detailed resource linked from the above stated thread is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it#441425  . Don't forget to check that.

Answer (score 1):

just add the ad placeholders on the all the pages. Google will automatically put different ads on them.
refer https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9187160?hl=en&visit_id=637001738277494464-3967545114&rd=1

Comment: OK so this is not against TOS?  To be clear its 1 URL, and its loading the content from an AJAX call and getting the additional data from JSON

For even more context, the site in question is https://www.imvuoutfits.com/